# Install apk FileProvider

Tags: android

I need to download .apk from server and promt user to install it. Its an actual update of b2b app and not malware.

For new android versions i need to use FileProvider.

Download works fine with download manager and on download is also triggered.
File is visible in device file explorer and File apk has correct path.
Allowed it in unknown apps.

Full app path: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.trebovanje/files/Download/update_1.0-5.apk

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>

<provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

And the code for install intent:

```
File apk = new File(Uri.parse(file).getPath());
                            if(apk.exists()) {
                                MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                                String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(apk.getName());
                                String mimeType = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

                                if (mimeType == null) mimeType = "*/*";


                                Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                promptInstall.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
                                promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {    //new androids
                                    try {
                                        Uri data = getFileUri(getApplicationContext(), apk);
                                        promptInstall.setDataAndType(data, mimeType);
                                        startActivity(promptInstall);
                                    }catch(Exception e){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }else{  //old anrdoids
                                    Uri data = Uri.fromFile(apk);
                                    promptInstall.setDataAndType(data, mimeType);
                                    startActivity(promptInstall);
                                }
                            }

 private Uri getFileUri(Context context, File file) {
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    }
```

I get always get "there is a problem parsing the package".

Comment: `and File apk has correct path.` Please tell full path.

Comment: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.trebovanje/files/Download/update_1.0-5.apk

Comment: A full path is without file:// in front. Confusing! A file uri is on old android. Why didnt you tell for which Android version you have problems? We dont know what happens.

Comment: file = file.substring(7);  this solved it. I need to make it work for 5+ androids. Thanks.